# redirecting authorized users to certain pages

Tags: model-view-controller, identity

I used the identity to assign roles to users.now I want to redirect users according to their role to certain pages.for example user with role"user" after login redirects to a page says" hello user".different from that of admin and so on.I have created the pages and validate authorization each .but where should I redirect after login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply change the login post action to check the user and redirect to the correct view.

Create separate view for normal users.

NormalUser.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Normal User";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Hello User!</h2>
```

Inside the controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
    public ActionResult NormalUser()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello normal user.";

        return View();
    }
```

Then Login post action

```
// POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                var userRole = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

                if (userRole.Any(role => role == "user"))
                {
                    RedirectToAction("NormalUser", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Check this [github](https://github.com/TechWhizIn/asp.net-Identity-framework-rolemanager-sample) Project to get the code.